# Script system in application

Tags: c++, python, boost, system

I'm developing a game and now I want to make script system for it.

Now I have abstract class **Object** which is inherited by all game objects. I have to write a lot of technical code, add new object type into **enum**, register parser function for each object (that function parses object's params from file).

I don't want to make such work. So the idea is to get some script system (boost.python for example, because I'm using boost in my project). Each object will be a simple python-script, at c++ side I just load and run all that scripts.

Python isn't hard -typed so I can register functions, build types dynamically without storing enum, etc. The only bad part is writing a lot of binding-code but It makes only once.

Are my ideas right?

Comment: As much as I love Python as a language, if you want a data description- and simple scripting language that is easily integrated with C and C++, I'd suggest Lua.

Comment: @delnan the question mostly is not about script language, but about idea of script usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give us a rough idea of how large the game is going to be?

If you're not careful, you could give yourself a lot of extra work without much benefit, but with some planning it sounds like it *might* help. The important questions are "What parts of the program do I want to simplify?", "Do I need a scripting language to simplify them? and "Can the scripting language simplify them?".

You mentioned that you don't want to have to manually parse files. Python's pickle module could handle serialization for you, but so could .NET. If you're using Visual Studio, then you may find it easier to write the code in C# than in Python.

You should also look for ways to simplify your code without adding a new language. For example, you might be able to create a simple binary file format and store your data structures without much parsing. There are probably other things you can do, but that would require more detailed knowledge of the program.